# Cannot Get JARs from Maven for ElasticSearch Shield Plugin

Tags: java, maven, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-shield

I'm not able to get maven to pull this dependencies.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.elasticsearch.plugin</groupId>
   <artifactId>shield</artifactId>
   <version>2.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

The only 2 files that are in the folder are:

shield-2.4.1.jar.lastUpdated and shield-2.4.1.pom.lastUpdated

What could have gone wrong? Here's the URL to the repository.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch.plugin/shield/2.4.1

Comment: Did you add elasticsearch maven repository to repositories list?

Comment: I just realized that was the issue as well. Thanks.